# iCal Google Sync -- how to get rid of folders (delegates)?

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar, ical, folders, google-calendar

I've got my calendars in Google, but when I sync them with iCal I get all these ugly folders. How can I clean this up?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Since late 2012, you can add [additional calendars to your main CalDAV account](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99358) by going to https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect. After you have done this, you can uncheck the delegate calendars in the iCal settings.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. It still works as of Sep 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You cannot easily clean that up.

Long Answer:  When you have delegate calendars, that typically means that you are given permission to view (maybe edit) someone else's calendar.  This is why there is special interface to deal with delegation and they are grouped in their own section of the calendar list.

Behind the scenes, google treats each calendar you create as its own principal (almost like its own account), so iCal treats all the non default calendars as delegates.  To confuse things further, you can actually can share google calendars so iCal could never tell the difference between an actual shared calendar and new calendar you added.

The only solution is to move all your events into the default calendar or move your calendars to a service which handles multiple calendars in a better way (Yahoo, Exchange, iCalServer)